# Git alias errors out, while running it in CLI always works

Tags: git, command-line-interface, zsh, alias

Running `$ git commit --amend --no-edit` in the CLI works.

When I alias it, in `~/.zshrc`

`alias gam="git commit --amend --no-edit"`

and run it..

`$ gam`

```
fatal: Stray .git/rebase-apply directory found.
Use "git am --abort" to remove it.
```

I run `git am --abort` then try to run the alias `gam` again..

`$ gam`

It just hangs... and never completes.

So I kill it and run it again.. which results in

```
fatal: Stray .git/rebase-apply directory found.
Use "git am --abort" to remove it.
```

Why would the alias mess things up, while running the command straight in the CLI work?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, but I'm using bash. Can you specify more about your environment, shell and version, OS, etc?

Comment: Note that this is more a question about zsh itself, since this alias is a zsh alias. To use a *Git* alias, add an `alias.gam` that expands to `commit --amend --noedit`; this may sidestep whatever issue you're having with zsh.

Comment: @GN. _running the command straight in the CLI _ In the variant, where you are **not** "straigth in the CLI" (whatever this means), how are you running the command then?

Comment: @GN.: Do a `type gam` and post the output.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ZSH on a Mac. Git 2.24.3

Comment: @user1934428 it means NOT using an alias

Answer (score 2):

The error message :

> Use "git am --abort" to remove it.

mentions `git am`, which shouldn't be triggered at all by `git commit --amend --noedit`.

Your alias is probably taken over by something else (another alias ? a zsh function ?) which tries to run `git am <something>`.

---

Check your zsh setup : I know of `type gam` in bash to get an accurate description of what is targeted when invoking `gam` ; I'm not fluent in zsh, try one of the following : `whence gam`, `type gam` or `which gam`.

Once you have spotted the offender, either remove the offending name, or choose another alias for your own command.

As suggested by @torek, you can also define a git alias :

```
$ git config alias.gam 'commit --amend --noedit'

# you can now run :
$ git gam
```